# Adding same description to many files in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, metadata, photo-management, lightroom-catalog

How do I add the same caption/description to multiple files using Lightroom?
I tried to select all the photos and edit the caption in the Metadata panel but it only applies the changes on a single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add/change meta information to more than one photo (when more than one is selected) you should select "Selected Photos" in Library module, specific meta window:
[image]

Unfortunately this setting is not stored in the library data so you should set it every time you start new instance of Lightroom (even with existing library)